# A Well-Known Splitting of a Fundamental Group of a Polygon of Groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

In "The Residual Finiteness of Negatively Curved Polygons of Finite Groups," Dani Wise makes reference to a 'well-known splitting of the fundamental group of a non-positively curved n-gon of groups' ($n \geq 4$). This splitting, he says, occurs along an internal line segment which cuts the polygon in such a way that at least two vertices are left on either side of the segment (pg. 4).

Wise gives more details of this splitting in a special case later in the paper. I'm curious to know more about the splitting in its full generality--are there any sources I can look at?

Comment: is "fundamental group" in the sense of Bass-Serre? (I usually call it "Bass-Serre fundamental group" to make it clear)

Comment: Wise may be overstating the case when he describes the splitting as "well known".  (Or it may have been better known in the past than it is now.)  I don't think this splitting has been considered by any recent authors other than Wise himself. The splitting was probably known to Stallings, though, and perhaps appears in one of his papers.